# Formulas in columnsets using ConTeXt

Tags: context

I tried out ConTeXt, where I found that columnsets worked just fine---until I put math into them. The below code produces an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\definecolumnset[TwoColumns][n=2]

\starttext

\startcolumnset[TwoColumns]

\startlines % enforce line breaks
Starlight, star bright,
first star I see tonight;
\stoplines

\column

\startlines
I wish I may, I wish I might $u$
have the wish I wish tonight.
\startformula
u^2 + v^2 = 0.
\stopformula
\stoplines

\stopcolumnset

\stoptext
```

Comment: Move the formula outside of the `lines` environment.

Comment: So all normal text goes in `lines`? What is the idea of that?

Comment: No, the `lines` environment should only be used for poems and other simple texts where you want a line break after each line in your input. Normal text and other mechanism like floats or display formulas should be written outside of the `lines` environment.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Do you want to write up an answer?